# How to get Selected Index from DataList(B) that is inside DataList(A)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datalist

I cannot get the Index of a DataList that is inside a DataList.

I have a DataList inside a DataList.

To clarify the Image:

```
<DataList ID="A">
         <DataList ID="B">
         </DataList>
   </DataList>
```

I need the Selected Index value of DataList B so I can use it in MySql table.

I tried in CS to get the Index value by:

```
DataList BDL = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("B");
int Index = BDL.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
```

But it always returned this Error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

BDL was null.

```
protected void BDataList_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
                DataList BDL= (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("BDataList");
                int index = e.Item.ItemIndex;
                MyLabel.Text = "" + BDL.SelectedIndex;
    }




<DataList ID="A" OnItemDataBound="ADataList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ADataList_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="ID">
         <DataList ID="B" OnItemCommand="BDataList_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="ID">
         </DataList>
</DataList>
```

Comment: Please, I need help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem: https://forums.asp.net/t/2154278.aspx?How+to+get+Selected+Index+from+DataList+B+that+is+inside+DataList+A+

I just had to do

```
DataList BDL =    e.Item.NamingContainer as DataList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataList BDL = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("B");
int Index = BDL.DataKeys[BDL.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
```

I think you used same index for two datalist. This code maybe wrong for you but your algoritm should be like this:

1. Get selected second Datalist
2. Get selected value in second list